# python django add variable to session from function and access it from another view function at same time

Tags: python, django, session

I'm trying to add session variable but it is not accessible from another function while the first function is still running, example is below

```
def index(request):
   request.session['logs'] = []  #I define the new variable here in session
  return render(request,"index.html")

def assigntoken(request):
   #I got list of users from post request to assign token to each of them I call a class called AssignToken
    v = AssignToken() 
    #AssignToken class has attribute called log_lst I assign it to session
    request.session['log'] = v.log_lst #by making v global I can access it from another function while it still running, but request.session['logs'] is still empty until function finish, why?
    v.start(users)  #this will start loop in users list to assign tokens
    return redirect('/result')

def result(request):
    #while assigntoken function still running I should be able to access /result to see live logs but when I try to access request.session['logs'] I found it empty, it only has data after assigntoken finish running
    context = {'logs':request.session['logs']}
    return render(request,"results.html",context)
```

Comment: Note that this is a strange thing to do with sessions, which is why this kind of on-the-fly updating isn't really documented.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for info, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to post a new question describing exactly what your goals are and asking about possible architectures. There's not enough information here to offer much advice beyond answering your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are [saved by `SessionMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e04209e181c99ac16ca769d115ac640015a83757/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L58) after the view completes. So it makes sense that you wouldn't see your changes while the request is still processing.

Instead you can try manually saving the session inside the view with `request.session.save()`.

Comment: thanks, when I did request.session.save() first log line appeared in request.session['logs'] but request.session['logs'] still not updated when v.log_lst is updated until view completes, I want request.session['logs'] to act as a pointer to v.log_lst and get updated when this object list updated

Comment: @Amr: Each request is handled in its own memory space; indeed, in many deployment scenarios your two requests will not even be handled by the same computer. So there's no way for the session in one request to be a pointer to an object in another. You will need to explicitly save every time you want the results to be seen by other requests.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a better way to do this?